# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'histplot'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to plot using [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) on the Titanic Dataset in Kaggle's Jupyter Notebook.

This is my code:

```
sns.histplot(train, x = "Age", hue="Sex")
```

But it's throwing me this error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d14c3b5a0670> in <module>
----> 1 sns.histplot(train, x = "Age", hue="Sex")

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'histplot'
```

I have made sure to import seaborn (previous plots using `sns.barplot` worked fine).

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.15.6, and Seaborn version 0.11.0.

Could somebody point out what went wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you have a standard python installation, update with `pip`:

```
pip install -U seaborn
```

If you are using an Anaconda distribution, at the `anaconda` prompt `(base)` environment, or activate the appropriate environment:

```
# update all the packages in the environment
conda update --all

# or 
conda update seaborn
```

See [Anaconda: Managing Packages](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html)

Answer (score 7):

Just in order to extend the answer from Ahsan Goheer.
Try updating seaborn with:

```
pip install -U seaborn
```

Then restart the Notebook's kernel.
Should work by now

Comment: This should be a comment and not a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Upgrade your seaborn

pip install seaborn --upgrade

Step 2: Restart Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

If all the previous method fail, it is very likely you named your file as "**seaborn.py**".

Please rename it from "**seaborn.py**" to something else like "**plot_seaborn.py**"