# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'histplot' without reassign sns before

Tags: python, attributes, seaborn, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to create chart just like in seaborn [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) that looks like this:
[image]

on my dataframe with the following script:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import pickle
import seaborn as sns



g = sns.PairGrid(df_num, hue="NDVI")
g.map_diag(sns.histplot, hue=None, color=".3")
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)
g.add_legend()
```

but I get the error message:

> AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'histplot'

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815227/attributeerror-module-seaborn-has-no-attribute-histplot) post regard teh same issue but I couldn't solve it on my notebook. I'm working with jupyterlab notebookk on a server, I haven't reassigned "sns" before to any other variable, I think I have the most updated version (I have install the package again using pip install).

My qeustion is what else can throw this error? what am I missing? is there any way to bypass it?

Comment: What version of seaborn are you using? `print(sns.__version__)`

Comment: @DavidG version 0.10.1

Comment: `histplot` was added in version 0.11, see the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html)